# Grails GSP render problem

Tags: grails, grails-orm, gsp

I've got a domain class which I want to, at run time, do a database call to populate a list of objects as a property. I have a tree with a 'headMember' property and that property is an object which has the following function:

```
def marriages = {
    def marriages = Marriage.findAll("from Marriage as m where m.mainMember.name=:name", [name:name])
    return [marriages:marriages]
}
```

in my GSP, I use `${tree?.headMember?.marriages}` to access the 'headMember' property of the model which is passed to the view 'tree' from the following function in the relevant controller:

```
def show = {
        def tree = Tree.get(params.id)
        render(view:'show', model:[tree:tree])
    }
```

when I view this in my browser, i get:

```
Member$_closure1@3708ab98
```

where I'd expect a list.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call marriages, you are calling a closure and this closure is returned. I think that you should rework it to be a method, something like that:

```
static transients = ['marriages'] // tell hibernate that marriages is not a persistent property

List<Marriages> getMarriages(){
    return Marriage.findAll("from Marriage as m where m.mainMember.name=:name", [name:name])    
}
```

This way, when you call `${tree?.headMember?.marriages}` in your GSP, the `getMarriages()` method is called and list of marriages should be returned.

Comment: Could you show how does your Tree and headMember domain classes look like?

Comment: I actually made an error when implementing your solution. It works fine! Thank you very much :-)